# Where can I get time series data set on 2016 presidential election polls?

Tags: time-series

I am looking for a time series data set on 2016 election polls for analysis. Can anyone suggest some good source?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about them.....hmmm!!